# A Simple Node.JS Benchmark

Tags: javascript, node.js, benchmarking

I am trying to determine if this is a fair benchmark.  The goal is trying to see how many concurrent connections vs payloads of various size Node.JS can handle.  The code is below.

```
var express = require('express');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();


var data;

var filename = process.argv[2] || './start.json';
console.log("Using: " + filename);
data = fs.readFileSync(filename);

var blockSize = 250000;
app.get('/start', function (req, res) {
  // Break up data in blocks.  Works to super high concurrents.
  // for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=blockSize)
  //   res.write(data.slice(i, i+blockSize));  

   // Can only handle about 600 concurrent requests if datasize > 500KB
   res.send(data);
});



app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Listing on 3000.');
});
```

As stated in the comments, if the payload size is larger than about 500KB and there have 500 concurrents it will get "connection reset by peer" at the load testing client.   If you slice the data up and write it in chunks it can survive to much higher concurrents before that starts.  Both stock node and express exhibit this behavior.

Comment: The problem is the majority of the data is in RAM. So for large payloads it boils down to how long it takes to memcpy(). This is exactly the kinds of workload that node cannot handle well. Node is optimised for I/O, not RAM processing. You'll get much better concurrency opening the file as a read stream and pipe it to the client. Doing that will shift almost all the load to the OS instead of node and if you are on Linux or Solaris you'll get a huge boost from the optimised filesystem drivers.

Comment: On the other hand, for small payloads you'll often get better performance keeping the data in RAM. So it depends really.

Comment: The CPU pegs out to 100% when the data size is larger which for node is obviously really bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = fs.readFileSync(filename);
```

Sync methods are nodejs killers. It actually block the event loop for **ALL** request, making performances really really bad.

Try this :

```
var express = require('express');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var filename = process.argv[2] || './start.json';

var blockSize = 250000;
app.get('/start', function (req, res) {
  // Break up data in blocks.  Works to super high concurrents.
  // for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=blockSize)
  //   res.write(data.slice(i, i+blockSize));  

   // Can only handle about 600 concurrent requests if datasize > 500KB
   console.log("Using: " + filename);

   fs.readFile(filename, function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.send(data);
   });

});



app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Listing on 3000.');
});
```

Comment: If you notice it happens on start of the script exactly once.  The point is not to benchmark the loading of the file--only the transfer.  So the data is in memory before the server even listens to connections.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could create a read stream and pipe it, here is the example based on your code

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

var data;

var filename = process.argv[2] || './data.json';
console.log("Using: " + filename);
data = fs.readFileSync(filename);

var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);

app.get('/start', function (req, res) {
  // Can only handle about 600 concurrent requests if datasize > 500KB
  //res.send(data);
  readStream.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: This was another idea I'd had.  Based on how it performs I am willing to bet send() does that behind the scenes.  If you put the readStream creation in /start it performs exactly as sending the raw stream.

Comment: it might be the case. I tested both solutions with very similar results.

Comment: Also, even funnier, if you do a large file (30MB) it's even better than Go at the same test.  Not expected.